# Lazy regex with OR

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have strings of the form:

```
greengrocerabc
sandwichcba
oscardcba
```

I'd like to lazily match `abc`, `abcd` and `abcde`, so I can get the first component. So something like

```
sub("^(.+)(abc|cba|dcba)", "\\1", "oscardcba") => "oscar"
```

However,  regexp `OR` greedy matches `cba` and I get `oscard`

How can I lazy match this `OR`? The language is R, but it can can act like grep or perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then make the quantifier non-greedy:

```
^(.+?)(abc|cba|dcba)
```

This way, the capture group will only contain the shortest possible match (which will not include `abc`, `cba` or `dcba`).

**Further reading:**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/